# Python: Add aggregated columns to DataFrame based on the Key and additional conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, melt

I have 2 dataframes in the following view:
`dogs` dataframe is:

```
DogID   PuppyName1  PuppyName2  PuppyName3  PuppyName4   DogWeight
Dog1       Nick         NaN         NaN      NaN            12.7
Dog2       Jack         Fox         Rex      NaN            15.5         
Dog3       Snack        NaN         NaN      NaN            10.2
Dog4       Yosee        Petty       NaN      NaN            16.9
```

`puppyWeights` dataframe is:

```
PuppyName   Jan17  Jun18  Dec18  April19   
Nick         0.8    1.7     3.7     4.6
Jack         0.6    1.3     2.8     3.5        
Fox          0.9    1.7     3.4     4.3
Rex          1.0    2.3     3.0     4.2
Snack        0.8    1.7     2.8     4.4
Yosee        0.6    1.2     3.1     4.3
Petty        0.5    1.3     2.8     3.5
```

I need to add information about puppies weight by Months to the `Dogs` dataframe based on `PuppyWeights` dataframe. If Dog has more than 1 child, for instance: `Dog2`, `Dog3`-> I need to take mean of the weight values by `PuppyName` for each Month. For example: 
`Dog2` should be average  between values for `Jack` and `Fox`in `PuppyWeights` table:

```
DogID   Jan17  Jun18  Dec18  April19   DogWeight
Dog2     0.75  1.5     3.1     3.9        15.5
```

I tried to use `melt` function to convert `['PuppyName1',  'PuppyName2',  'PuppyName3',  'PuppyName4']` columns into rows.

But, I don't have idea how to add months information to `dogs` dataframe with aggregation by mean when dog has more than one child.

`df2 = dogs.melt(id_vars=['DogID','DogWeight'], var_name="Puppies", value_name='PuppyName')`

Desired Output is:

```
DogID   Jan17  Jun18  Dec18  April19   DogWeight
Dog1     0.8    1.7    3.7     4.6        12.7     
Dog2     0.75   1.5    3.1     3.9        15.5   
Dog3     0.8    1.7    2.8     4.4        10.2
Dog4     0.55   1.25   2.95    3.9        16.9
```

How I can add weight information by Month to the `dogs` dataframe?

I'd appreciate for any idea. Thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way `melt` the `dogs` , then `merge` and `groupby`

```
df2 = dogs.melt(id_vars=['DogID','DogWeight'], var_name="Puppies", value_name='PuppyName').dropna()

df2.merge(df,on='PuppyName',how='left').groupby('DogID').mean()
Out[423]: 
       DogWeight     Jan17     Jun18     Dec18  April19
DogID                                                  
Dog1        12.7  0.800000  1.700000  3.700000      4.6
Dog2        15.5  0.833333  1.766667  3.066667      4.0
Dog3        10.2  0.800000  1.700000  2.800000      4.4
Dog4        16.9  0.550000  1.250000  2.950000      3.9
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for help. That what I asked.